# How to use bundle file created by browserify?

Tags: javascript, frontend, browserify, web-frontend

I made 4 javascript files, A,B,C,D, and they will export 4 modules A,B,C,D. Their dependency is A->B->C->D. I key in the command

```
browserify A.js -o bundle.js
```

and a bundle file include A,B,C,D is created. In the html file, i got

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
<script src="client.js"></script>
```

inside the client.js, i got

```
var a = new A();
```

the console will print an error that A is not defined.
However, the client.js will work if i delete the 'require' and module.exports on all js file and do this in html file

```
<script src = "D.js"></script>
<script src = "C.js"></script>
<script src = "B.js"></script>
<script src = "A.js"></script>
<script src = "client.js"></script>
```

Does anyone have any idea about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a [standalone](https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#standalone) bundle which will add a variable to the global execution context, this is done with the `--standalone <name>` option

```
browserify A.js --standalone A -o bundle.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the standalone option that Mauricio proposed, you can also have browserify create a require function so you can use the require function in the browser.

```
browserify -r ./A.js:a_module ./B.js ./C.js ./D.js -o bundle.js
```

Then your client.js file can do this:

```
var a_module = require('a_module');
var a = new a_module.A();
```

This is the [external requires](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#external-requires) option.